# Laravel error with routes/controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just getting started with laravel and mvc. When I"m setting a controller in routes.php it's not working. Please see my code.

routes.php (in app/http/routes.php):

```
Route::get('index', 'Blog\Controller\Article@showIndex');
```

Article.php (in app//http/controllers/Article.php)

```
<?php

 namespace Blog\Controller;

 use View;
 use BaseController;

 class Article extends BaseController
 {
 public function showIndex()
 {
    return View::make('test');
 }

}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm getting the error:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:

Thankyou.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Sorry for that the error is: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:

Comment: And you got this on a `POST` request on `http://localhost/index`?

Comment: yes but if I say get it also does not work

Answer (score 0):

In my routes i included: URL::setRootControllerNamespace('App\Http\Controllers');

and just used the typical route format Controller@method and its been working. Mind you i am working on laravel5 framework